# SQL Server waiting stat interpretation

Tags: sql-server

I have run the below query and got the below results. Can someone tell me how to interpret that? in Microsoft document it says "compare it with baseline" what if I do not have any base line?

Query:

```
SELECT wait_type,
       waiting_tasks_count,
       wait_time_ms,
       signal_wait_time_ms

FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE wait_type LIKE 'PAGEIOLATCH%'
ORDER BY wait_type
```

Results:

```
wait_type   waiting_tasks_count     wait_time_ms    signal_wait_time_ms

PAGEIOLATCH_DT  0                   0                   0
PAGEIOLATCH_EX  248980842           1097771451          5018277
PAGEIOLATCH_KP  0                   0                   0
PAGEIOLATCH_NL  0                   0                   0
PAGEIOLATCH_SH  1078041651          5763754764          68444188
PAGEIOLATCH_UP  2862654             29875699            259859
```

Comment: it's not really possible to infer anything from that without more context.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[sql]` and `[server]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[sql-server]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Your baseline is the same query a few moments ago. The difference of the numbers is what has been going on in the meantime.

Comment: Your table does not tell us anything. At first, you have to sort by `wait_time_ms` DESC and see the biggest wait in your system. Then you have to re-measure it after some time to see the change. Try [Paul Randal's Script] (http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/)